# Using php_mapscript on WAMP?

Tags: mapserver, apache, mapscript, dll

I use WAMP in my Windows, and I want to use phpmapscript for programming. I've copied the phpmapscript.dll file to C: \ wamp64 \ bin \ php \ php5.6.25 \ ext and I added the "extension = php_mapscript.dll" in the php.ini file. 
In the wamp extension menu, this plugin is checked and added to this list
[image: WAMP extension list]

but when I use the -phpinfo- command , I do not see this plugin.
[image: phpinfo]

I have a lots projects inside WAMP and I can not use ms4w on my system.

Can you guide me?